# File transfer hangs (but without error) between node.js server and socket.io client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to transfer a file with node.js using socket.io (socket.io-client) and delivery.

I tried to do this on server-side:

```
//// server.js
var socket  = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
var dl  = require('delivery');
var fs  = require('fs');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    log( "Sockets connected" );
    delivery = dl.listen(socket);
    delivery.connect();
    delivery.on('delivery.connect',function(delivery){
        delivery.send({
            name: 'file1.zip',
            path : './file1.zip'
        });
        delivery.on('send.success',function(file){
            console.log('File sent successfully!');
        });
    });
});
```

And this on client-side:

```
//// client.js
var io  = require('socket.io-client');
var dl  = require('delivery');
var fs  = require('fs');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
socket.on('connection', function(socket){
    var delivery = dl.listen(socket);
    delivery.on('receive.success',function(file){
        fs.writeFile(file.name, file.buffer, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('File could not be saved: ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log('File ' + file.name + " saved");
            };
        });
    });
});
```

On execution, there is no error, but it hangs.
Server-side:

```
$ node server.js 
info  - socket.io started
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized Bbzo928wAyTjDX8v06Ic
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/Bbzo928wAyTjDX8v06Ic
debug - set heartbeat interval for client Bbzo928wAyTjDX8v06Ic
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
debug - emitting heartbeat for client Bbzo928wAyTjDX8v06Ic
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client Bbzo928wAyTjDX8v06Ic
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client Bbzo928wAyTjDX8v06Ic
debug - set heartbeat interval for client Bbzo928wAyTjDX8v06Ic
```

And on client-side there is no output:

```
$ node client.js
```

Do anyone know, what goes wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure you can just send a binary file over the socket like that, and why are you using node.js requires and syntax on the client side ?

Comment: @adeneo the client isn't a browser but another Node app, and [the `delivery` module](https://npmjs.org/package/delivery) is being used

Comment: @robertklep - That explains it, I sorta figured as much but it just said "client side". Never used that module, just used [binary.js](http://binaryjs.com/) to send files like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the version of `delivery` in the NPM repository is out of date, and contains some bugs. You should install the latest version from GitHub:

```
$ npm install git+https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js.git
```

Next, you're mixing up some client and server parts, specifically the events that each has to handle. This (somewhat, see below) works for me:

```
//// server.js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
var dl = require('delivery');
var fs = require('fs');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('server: a new client connected');
  var delivery = dl.listen(socket);
  delivery.on('delivery.connect', function(delivery) {
    delivery.send({
      name: 'file1.zip',
      path : './file1.zip'
    });
    delivery.on('send.success', function(file) {
      console.log('File sent successfully!');
    });
  });
});

//// client.js
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var dl = require('delivery');
var fs = require('fs');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('client: connected to server');
  var delivery = dl.listen(socket);
  delivery.connect();
  delivery.on('receive.success', function(file) {
    // TODO: fs.writeFile(...);
  });
});
```

However, it seems that the `receive.success` event is delivered to the client twice, at least for me. I'm not sure why (I'm not overly familiar with `delivery`).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, receive.success is getting hit twice !